# How to remove items from queryset based on condition and then return as json response in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-serializer

I am doing join operation using select_related() and filtering records using below code

```
class ActiveclientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Ruledefinitions.objects.select_related('pmdclinicalruleid').filter(pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate__lt = timezone.now(),pmdclinicalruleid__retireddate__gt = timezone.now())
 serializer_class = RuledefinitionsSerializer
```

In the above code, is it possible to check whether the first item from queryset has rulename field value as empty and if it is empty i need to return remaining queryset items in json response if not empty return all items as json response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with checking the first element ?

```
class ActiveclientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ruledefinitions.objects.select_related('pmdclinicalruleid')
    serializer_class = RuledefinitionsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        now = timezone.now
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(
            pmdclinicalruleid__effectivedate__lt=now,
            pmdclinicalruleid__retireddate__gt=now,
        )
        first_item = queryset.first()
    
        if first_item is not None and not first_item.rulename:
            queryset = queryset[1:]

    return queryset
```

Your filter on timezone.now() is only executed once: when your classe is defined. So any call to this method should not be in the classe definition, but called every request.

In your actual implementation, now would be called as soon as you start the server. Two weeks later, the filter would still be at the same date.

Comment: Precision: you'd need to override get_queryset(self), and not queryset directly.

Comment: That's right, I didn't even read the request... Edited to clean this up.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Its working pretty good, Could you please explain what "if first_item is not None and not first_item.rulename:" this line of code does? I only need to check the first_item has whether rulename field empty or null. If empty or null, need to ignore the first item of queryset

Comment: The 'first' method returns None if the queryset does not contain any item. So you need to make sure you have a first item. Trying to access first_item.rulename when first_item is None will raise an AttributeError

Comment: Okay thats clear. so i need to add additionally, first_item.rulename !== '' or first_item.rulename !== None inside if loop to validate my conditions right?

Comment: not first_item.rulename will match either None or ''...